# How can i make a set in my list in python?

Tags: python, list, set

I need to make this

```
[['#', '#', '#', '#', '#', '#', '#'], ['#', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', '#'], ['#', ' ', '$', '+', '$', ' ', '#'], ['#', '.', '*', '#', '*', '.', '#'], ['#', ' ', '$', '.', '$', ' ', '#'], ['#', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', '#'], ['#', '#', '#', '#', '#', '#', '#']]
```

turn into this

```
      0   1   2   3   4   5   6 
    +---+---+---+---+---+---+---+
  0 | # | # | # | # | # | # | # |
    +---+---+---+---+---+---+---+
  1 | # |   |   |   |   |   | # |
    +---+---+---+---+---+---+---+
  2 | # |   | $ | + | $ |   | # |
    +---+---+---+---+---+---+---+
  3 | # | . | * | # | * | . | # |
    +---+---+---+---+---+---+---+
  4 | # |   | $ | . | $ |   | # |
    +---+---+---+---+---+---+---+
  5 | # |   |   |   |   |   | # |
    +---+---+---+---+---+---+---+
  6 | # | # | # | # | # | # | # |
    +---+---+---+---+---+---+---+
```

Comment: nice work sebastian

Comment: What do you mean set? Do you mean you want to print it out like that?

Comment: @SebastianPaaskeTørhol: You should get an award for your edit

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should try to do the complete code, but the base code is

```
x = [['#', '#', '#', '#', '#', '#', '#'], ['#', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', '#'], ['#', ' ', '$', '+', '$', ' ', '#'], ['#', '.', '*', '#', '*', '.', '#'], ['#', ' ', '$', '.', '$', ' ', '#'], ['#', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', '#'], ['#', '#', '#', '#', '#', '#', '#']]
for i in x: #For each element in x
    print '| ', 
    for k in i: #For each element in each element of x
        print k, ' | ', #Print it
    print
```